# How to update form "item name" on selecting an item from drop down

Tags: php, forms, paypal, drop-down-menu

Is it possible to update a hidden value "item name" in a form when an item in the drop down menu is selected?

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="PHOTOID 2 Product MUG" />
```

Drop Down List: (populated from datase.

mug £9.99

a4 print £2.50

etc

etc

When an item is selected, but before the add to cart button is pressed it is possible to update the item_name value? Otherwise I just get the photo ID sent to the cart. This adds the item to paypal shopping cart, I can only have one item name then the populated options list below. I hope that makes sense.

Thank in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your drop-down menu is a `<select>` tag, then you can do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateItemName() {
  var select = document.getElementById('select_stuff');
  var field = document.getElementById('item_name');

  field.value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
};
</script>

<input type="hidden" name="item_name" id="item_name" value="" />

<select name="select_stuff" id="select_stuff" onchange="updateItemName()">
  <option value="Stuff 1" >Stuff 1</option>
  <option value="Stuff 2">Stuff 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Perfect! Brilliant! Thank you! That's exactly what I needed! Just one more thing how can I add "PHOTOID<?php echo $pid;?>" to the value. So it would update to "PHOTOID2 Stuff 1"when stuff 1 clicked!

Comment: field.value = "PHOTOID <?php echo $pid;?> " + select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

Comment: Woohoo! I got it! Thanks Imi. You're a star!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with javascript, but I'm not quite sure why you'd need to.  If you have a select with values and a hidden field that's supposed to take the same value as the select, then that mean you're submitting the same data twice.  Just use the value of the select control directly.

Comment: Unfortunately its for paypal shopping cart and you can only assign an "ammount" to the value of the option. It wont allow you to assign a name to the option, it only takes the name from the input item_name. (This is what I can make from it anyway!! I may be wrong. I have managed to do it with a bit of javascript now from Imi so its working. Thanks for your time though. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to do in javascript; trivial with jQuery. Let's pretend we have the following html:

```
<ul id="item-list">
   <li>One certain item</li>
   <li>Another one</li>
   ...
</ul>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" id="item_name" value="" id="the_id"/>
```

What you would do is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#item-list li').click(function() {
    $('#the_id').attr(name, $(this).text());
});
</script>
```

That means:

as the user clicks on a li contained by the element with id item-list
assign to the element with id the_id, as name, the text contained by the li they just clicked.

---

Sorry, I just realized you wanted to change the name and not the value: fixed.